# Can Firebase ML Kit be used as Face Authentication

Tags: firebase-mlkit

Hi I am trying to build an App that register Users with their Face instead of the traditional Methods like Email or Password . So i used The Face Detection API from Ml Kit . But i can't really find a way for 
differentiating from different Faces. Is there a way for doing this in Ml Kit ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The built-in model in Firebase ML Kit detect faces, but doesn't recognize them.

If you want to accomplish the latter, you **can** build a custom model for that, for example by using [AutoML Vision Edge](https://firebase.google.com/docs/ml-kit/automl-image-labeling). Note that you'll need a pretty substantial set of (pre-classified) images to train such a model.

Comment: Sir thanks for answer but can you clarify the point of '' substantial  set of (pre-classified) images ''.

Comment: To train a custom model with AutoML Vision Edge you need to have a set of pre-classified images, so images that are already classified to the result set you want. To learn more about this, I highly recommend reading the documentation I linked, as it explains the process better than I can probably do here.